# Retrieving a returned string from AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to retrieve the contents of [this file](http://stream.lobant.net/ccfm.info) and save that to a string.

I've tried using AsyncTask (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/1427975)) and here is my class.

```
class RetreiveURLTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private Exception exception = null;
    public String ResultString = null;

    protected String doInBackground(Void ... something) {
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://stream.lobant.net/ccfm.info");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            String stream_url = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
            urlConnection.disconnect();

            return stream_url;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.exception = e;
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String stream_url) {
    // TODO: check this.exception 
    // TODO: do something with the feed
    if (this.exception != null)
        this.exception.printStackTrace();

    this.ResultString = stream_url;
    }
}
```

I've tried using my AsyncTask class like this:

```
  AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> stream_task = new RetreiveURLTask().execute();
  String stream_url = stream_task.ResultString;
```

but ResultString isn't recognised.

I'm confused about how this all works. Since the AsyncTask runs in the background, even if I could assign my string to one of the public variables, there is no guarentee that it will be valid when I make the assignment. Even if I were to use some kind of getResult() function, I would need to know when to call it so that the code has completed executing.

So, how is this usually done?

(Also, is my http read code ok?)

---

My ability: I can code, but am new to android.

Comment: stream_task.execute(); call

Comment: @StaceyAnne what do you want to do with the result string?

Comment: @Metalhead1247 I want to use it to open a MediaPlayer stream instance inside my main activity. I can stream fine using a hard-coded url, but would like to fetch one from another location instead.

Comment: @StaceyAnne initialize  public String ResultString = ""; in the main class that will do the trick

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an interface

```
new RetreiveURLTask(ActivityName.this).execute();
```

In your asyctask

```
TheInterface listener;
```

In the constructor

```
 public RetreiveURLTask (Context context)
{

    listener = (TheInterface) context;
}
```

The interface

```
public interface TheInterface {

    public void theMethod(String result);

     }
```

In onPostExecute

```
if (listener != null) 
  {
  listener.theMethod(stream_url);
  }
```

In your activity class implement the interface

```
 implements RetreiveURLTask.TheInterface
```

Implement the method

```
 @Override
 public void theMethod(String result) {
 // update ui using result
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// try this way

  RetreiveURLTask task = new RetreiveURLTask();
  task.execute();

 private void response(String responseData){
        // here you write your code which use responseData
 }
 class RetreiveURLTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private Exception exception = null;
        public String ResultString = null;

        protected String doInBackground(Void ... something) {
            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL("http://stream.lobant.net/ccfm.info");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                String stream_url = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
                urlConnection.disconnect();

                return stream_url;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.exception = e;
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String stream_url) {
            // TODO: check this.exception 
            // TODO: check this.exception 
            // TODO: do something with the feed
            super.onPostExecute(stream_url);
            response(stream_url)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make  this

```
        public String ResultString = "";
```

Global

Asynctask is not the main class here , that's the reason you get `ResultString cannot be resolved or is not a field`

make it  a global variable then you'll be able to access it

Answer (score 0):

The execution of the AsyncTask is started in the background, while the assignment is carried out immediately after the execution *began*. Therefore, the assignment is carried out before the execution of the AsyncTask is complete.

Your best bet is to conduct the assignment in the OnPostExecute() method.